# How to use carousel light on a data-bs-theme="dark" webpage

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-carousel

I am using a bootstrap carousel on a page with  `data-bs-theme="dark"` in the html tag - i.e. I am using a dark theme. Because of this, the carousel automatically changes to a dark theme. I want the indicators, the captions, and the controls to be white/light, but can't seem to change this ...

I tried in my css:

```
            .carousel-control-next-icon,
            .carousel-control-prev-icon {
            filter: invert(1);
            }
```

I've tried in the carousel parent element - carousel-light
I've tried adding  `data-bs-theme="light"` in the carousel tag. I just can't seem to get this carousel to invert colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default variable from Bootstrap `_variables.scss`

```
$carousel-dark-control-icon-filter:  invert(1) grayscale(100) !default;
```

which you may change it to your desired color in a dark-mode when use `data-bs-theme="dark"`

For example,

```
$carousel-dark-control-icon-filter:  $white;
```